# Qt not working with Symbian

Tags: qt, mobile, symbian, nokia, ovi

I cannot set up my Qt SDK so that it communicates with my Nokia C6-00. First af all, I cannot make sure what my Symbian version is. On the official web site they say I must have Symbian^3, but nothing from what Qt installs at Symbian^3 systems works. Links to installations under Symbian^1 install though.

I went thru the introduction to developing with Symbian and following it I have done the following:

1. Downloaded and installed Qt SDK 1.1.2.
2. Connected my Nokia C6-00 via USB to my computer.
3. Launched Nokia Ovi Suite
4. Installed App TRK for Symbian^1 5th edition on to my Symbian device
5. Installed Qt 4.6.3 on my Symbian
6. I have tried compiling as both Qt 4.6.3 and Qt 4.7.3 for symbian^1 and Symbian^3. Tried launching any of the examples or creating my own empty project - nothing has worked so far. Error: `OS-related error`.

I have tried all the possible combinations of installed software for Symbian^1 and Symbian^3 and it just does not work! I have also ried copying the *.sis files from the project folder directly onto my device, but it did not work either! It installed itself, claiming to be incompatible, but when I click on the icon in `Applications` folder, nothing happens.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me at my mistakes or suggest my another try.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is with step 4: `Installed App TRK for Symbian^1 5th edition on to my Symbian device`

Your phone is Symbian^3 indeed, uninstall TRK and install the right one, for Symbian^3.

Comment: Thx, I will follow your advice and reply to you!

Answer (score 0):

C6-00 is S60 5.0

http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/devices/nokia-c6-00/specifications#Software_applications

Please try latest Qt SDK and Qt 4.7.3. If you still meet issues, maybe you can submit bugreport for Qt SDK or Qt via https://bugreports.qt.io/ .

Comment: S60 5.0 is the name of the OS, but in the development it must either Symbian^1 or Symbian^3. This is where I get stuck.

Comment: Symbian is the name of OS, S60 is from Series 60 User Interface. You could check them in wikipedia.